# "Warning : TCP Connect to localhost:8094 failed" while Installing the Experience Optimization Query Service

Tags: fredhopper, web8.5, experience-optimization

While I am trying for Installing the Experience Optimization Query Service I face the below issue, reference for the step available in this [Link](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?action=home&pub=SDL%20Web-v5&lang=en-US#docid=GUID-C8CD469F-D436-44DC-8661-557D1DB7F4A1&addHistory=true&query=&scope=&tid=&filename=GUID-C8CD469F-D436-44DC-8661-557D1DB7F4A1.xml&resource=&inner_id=&toc=false&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-C8CD469F-D436-44DC-8661-557D1DB7F4A1).

Error:

> Server Error in '/' Application.
>   Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.
>   Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>   Exception Details: System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException: Unauthorized Request -- Please check your configuration settings to make sure your authentication details are correct.
>   An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Comment: Could you clarify exactly when you get this error?

Comment: while running the command "bin/installService.ps1 --auto-register" in powershell of the mentioned folder.

Comment: Hmm okay. What happens if you go directly to the URL in a browser? Maybe there is something else listening on that port already...

Comment: @PeterKjaer "This Page Can't be displayed" was the response I am getting while hitting the url directly in browser.

Comment: And if you look in the logs for the query service? Are there any errors?

Comment: Make sure you have Token service up and running..